# Could not add reference to WinRT C++ DLL project

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, clr, direct3d

**THE SCENARIO:**

I am making a [edit: native WinRT] C++ Direct X DLL project for Windows Store apps based on the "Direct3D App" Visual Studio code sample.

This must be a separate DLL project from my Windows Store App project because I will be using my XAML UserControl with Direct X renderer inside it both in the Windows 8 Metro app and a Windows Phone version of the app.

**THE PROBLEM:**

I cannot reference the C++ project in the C# Windows Store app project. Visual Studio refuses with the following words:

```
A reference to <project-name> could not be added.
```

I've seen suggestions to compile the C++ project using the /clr flag, but this is not compatible with:

- the /ZW flag required by some API within the project
- the "wrl.h" header
- a multitude of other command-line flags in the project settings

So the /clr flag does not appear to be an option in this situation.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I reference the C++ project so that I can use my XAML Direct X renderer within the C# Windows Store App project? Or is there a better alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by re-creating the C++ project as a `Windows Runtime Component` project. I had originally created the project from the `Class Library (Windows Store apps)` template. It must be that the Win RT template has some configuration settings which enable it to work.

After making this change, the project could be added as a reference in the C# project.

It is because of @user1610015's answer that I realised I was actually developing native Win RT code, not managed code, which lead me to try this solution - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The **/ZW** flag is for C++/CX projects. C++/CX is almost identical in syntax to managed C++ (C++/CLI), except that C++/CX is completely unmanaged. This may be what made you think you were developing managed C++, when in fact you weren't.

I haven't used C++/CX, but from what I've heard, Windows Runtime classes are COM classes. So I think you can use the **TlbImp.exe** tool from the Windows SDK to create a managed DLL from your unmanaged DLL, which you can then reference from your C# project. Try it and let me know if it works.

Another option is to talk to the Windows Runtime without C++/CX. While C++/CX makes Windows Runtime programming a lot easier, it's not strictly necessary. You can also use the WRL library. Since the WRL library is pure C++, it should also be usable from C++/CLI.

Comment: Thank you for this info - I had no idea that I wasn't developing unmanaged code. I didn't end up needing to try Tlbimp.exe - see my answer above.